# Which intonation is used in the sentence your home work or you cannot go out with your friends

Tags: intonation

Which intonation is used in the sentence

> Finish your home work or you cannot go out with your friends.

Answer (score 0):

There's more than one possible intonation.  To make the first part a calm serious effect you could use a low falling nuclear tone.  And to make the second express the contradictory "get out clause" (ie but if you do do your homework you may go out) a falling-rising intonation can be used.

The first part has falling intonation, descending from "fin-" to "home".  The second part has rising-falling. Rising from "you" to "your" and then falling through "friends"

There are other valid intonation contours.

Answer (score 0):

The intonation would depend on the speaker's patience, affability, tiredness, anger-management, dialect and so on.

This is approximately how a tired but patient UK mother might say it:

[image]

A man's voice would be lower of course.

(There's a dotted tie where, in the UK, we'd probably say *can't* rather than *cannot*.)